# How to change buttons class by click?

Tags: angular

I have script pushing (and splice) data to and from array.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EuFdfCLNIXKreNiADXy3?p=preview)

```ts
 <button
  *ngFor="#color of colors"
   [class.selected]="???????????" (click)="onPress(color)">
       {{color.name}}
 </button>
```

app.ts

```ts
onPress(color: Color) {
 this.selectedColors = color;
  if (this.hasColor(this.colorsArray,this.selectedColors.id)) {
    this.colorsArray.splice( this.colorsArray.indexOf(this.selectedColors.id),1);
  }
  else {
    this.colorsArray.push(this.selectedColors.id);
         }   
  }
```

How can i change class on all pressed buttons by click and change it back? Not switch ([like here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html)) 
Should i use ngClass or something like `[class.selected] ===`

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EuFdfCLNIXKreNiADXy3?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you want

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
 @View({
 template : `
 <div flex="100" layout="column" layout-xs="column" layout-sm="column">
  <button md-button  md-raised-button class="color"
      *ngFor="#color of colors"
      [class.selected]="isColorSelected(color)"
      (click)="onPress(color)">
      {{color.name}}
  </button>
  {{colorsArray}}
  </div>
  <div>selected: {{selectedColors | json}}</div>
  ` ,
  directives: []
})
export class App {

  public colors = COLORS;
          selectedColors : Color;
          colorsArray = [];
  selectedColors:Color[] = [];        

  onPress(color: Color) {
    var index = this.selectedColors.indexOf(color.id);
    console.log(index);
    if(index < 0) {
      console.log('add');
      if(index === -1) {
        this.selectedColors.push(color.id);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('remove');
      this.selectedColors.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }   

  isColorSelected(color) {
    return this.selectedColors.indexOf(color.id) != -1;
  }
 }
}
```

I also changed the CSS

```ts
button.color.selected {
  background : #fff;
}
```

Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/bhHbSd5ReCxtxRNI9ogx?p=preview

to increase the selectivity, otherwise the styles wouldn't be applied because `button.color` has higher selectivity than `.selected` alone.

Comment: It's great!! Thank you. And this      var index = this.selectedColors.indexOf(color.id);
    console.log(index);
    if(index < 0) {
      console.log('add');
      if(index === -1) {
        this.selectedColors.push(color.id);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('remove');
      this.selectedColors.splice(index, 1);
    }  very clean